# Want to prepare iPad App similar iPad Mail app

Tags: ipad

I want to create an iPad application with a similar user interface to Apple's Mail application, i.e:

- RootView controller (table view) on the left hand side of the split view for navigation with a multiple view hierarchy. When a table cell is selected a new table view is pushed on the left hand side
- The new view on the left hand side can then update the detail view. (Problem is arising at here because new view on the left hand side has lost connection with detail view)

For applying these feature we are using UISplitViewController.